# Bitmap font rendering issue

Tags: c, opengl, fonts

Learning OpenGL here. Trying to write a bitmap font rendering system.

I'm using [Hiero](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero) to generate the font file (Angel Code font format) and atlas (`.fnt` and `.png` files).

I first parse the font file reading in the font and character data. That part is easy. (I verified that the parsed results are indeed all correct)

```
// (typedefs) u32: unsigned int, r32: float, string: char*

struct font_character
{
    u32 Id;
    r32 X, Y;
    r32 Width, Height;
    r32 XOffset, YOffset;
    r32 XAdvance;
};

struct font_set
{
    string Name;
    u32 Atlas;
    r32 Size;
    u32 Stretch;
    u32 Smooth;
    u32 AntiAliasing;
    u32 Padding[4];
    u32 Spacing[2];
    u32 LineHeight;
    u32 BaseLine;
    r32 Width, Height;
    u32 CharacterCount;
    font_character Characters[128];
};

// Parsing related codes...

font_set FontLoad(string FilePath)
{
    font_set Result = {};

    string Content = ReadFile(FilePath);
    if (Content)
    {
        List(string) FontSettings;
        ListAlloc(FontSettings, 1024);

        bool DoneParsing = false;
        while(!DoneParsing)
        {
            token Token = GetToken(Content);
            switch(Token.Type)
            {
                case TokenType_EOF:
                    DoneParsing = true;
                    break;

                case TokenType_Unknown:
                    Assert(!"Unknown token in font file");
                    break;

                case TokenType_Number:
                case TokenType_String:
                case TokenType_Identifier:
                    ListPush(FontSettings, Token.Content);
                    break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0, Count = ListCount(FontSettings); i < Count; i += 2)
        {
            string SettingKey = FontSettings[i];
            string SettingValue = FontSettings[i + 1];

            if (StringEqual(SettingKey, "face"))
                Result.Name = SettingValue;
            else if (StringEqual(SettingKey, "size"))
                Result.Size = atoi(SettingValue);
            else if (StringEqual(SettingKey, "stretchH"))
                Result.Stretch = atoi(SettingValue);
            else if (StringEqual(SettingKey, "smooth"))
                Result.Smooth = atoi(SettingValue);
            else if (StringEqual(SettingKey, "aa"))
                Result.AntiAliasing = atoi(SettingValue);
            else if (StringEqual(SettingKey, "lineHeight"))
                Result.LineHeight = atoi(SettingValue);
            else if (StringEqual(SettingKey, "base"))
                Result.BaseLine = atoi(SettingValue);
            else if (StringEqual(SettingKey, "scaleW"))
                Result.Width = atoi(SettingValue);
            else if (StringEqual(SettingKey, "scaleH"))
                Result.Height = atoi(SettingValue);
            else if (StringEqual(SettingKey, "spacing"))
            {
                // Ascii(48) = Decimal(0)
                Result.Spacing[0] = SettingValue[0] - 48;
                Result.Spacing[1] = SettingValue[2] - 48;
            }
            else if (StringEqual(SettingKey, "padding"))
            {
                Result.Padding[0] = SettingValue[0] - 48;
                Result.Padding[1] = SettingValue[2] - 48;
                Result.Padding[2] = SettingValue[4] - 48;
                Result.Padding[3] = SettingValue[6] - 48;
            }
            else if (StringEqual(SettingKey, "char"))
            {
                font_character Character;

                // Although they're 10 pairs of data, we're gonna skip the last two cause we don't care about them
                For(u32, PairIndex, 8)
                {
                    string CharKey = FontSettings[(i + 1) + PairIndex * 2];
                    string CharValue = FontSettings[(i + 2) + PairIndex * 2];

                    if (StringEqual(CharKey, "id"))
                        Character.Id = atoi(CharValue);
                    else if (StringEqual(CharKey, "x"))
                        Character.X = atoi(CharValue);
                    else if (StringEqual(CharKey, "y"))
                        Character.Y = atoi(CharValue);
                    else if (StringEqual(CharKey, "width"))
                        Character.Width = atoi(CharValue);
                    else if (StringEqual(CharKey, "height"))
                        Character.Height = atoi(CharValue);
                    else if (StringEqual(CharKey, "xoffset"))
                        Character.XOffset = atoi(CharValue);
                    else if (StringEqual(CharKey, "yoffset"))
                        Character.YOffset = atoi(CharValue);
                    else if (StringEqual(CharKey, "xadvance"))
                        Character.XAdvance = atoi(CharValue);
                }

                Result.Characters[Result.CharacterCount++] = Character;
                i += 19;
            }
            else i--;
        }
    }

    // Load texture
    char TexturePath[256];
    sprintf(TexturePath, "%s.png", FilePath);
    Result.Atlas = TextureLoad(TexturePath); // loads texture from file via stbi_load, does glGenTexture, configures texture parameters etc.

    return (Result);
}
```

Then we get to rendering, which is where I'm struggling a bit. My understanding is that I need to use the character data I got from the font data to build quads that I could render to screen.

First, here's my shaders. Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 VertPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 VertUV;

out vec2 FragUV;

uniform mat4 Projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = Projection * vec4(VertPos, 0, 1);
    FragUV = VertUV;
}
```

And fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 FinalColor;
in vec2 FragUV;

uniform sampler2D FontAtlas;
uniform vec3 Color;

void main()
{
    FinalColor = vec4(Color, texture(FontAtlas, FragUV).a);
}
```

Here's how I load the font and render:

```
struct font_renderer
{
    string Text;
    v3 Color;
    r32 CurrentX;
    u32 VAO, VBO;
    u32 Initialized;
    u32 Shader;
};

// In an initialization function
font_set Font = FontLoad("res/fonts/Courier New.fnt");
u32 FontShader = ShaderLoadFromFile("Font.vert", "Font.frag");

// In an update/render function
font_renderer FontRenderer = {};
FontRenderer.Text = "A";
FontRenderer.Color = V3(1, 0, 0);
FontRenderer.CurrentX = 20;
FontRenderer.Shader = FontShader;

FontRender(&FontRenderer, &Font);
```

Rendering function (just trying to get something on the screen)

```
void FontRender(font_renderer *Renderer, font_set *Font)
{
    u32 NumChars = StringLength(Renderer->Text);

    u32 Size = NumChars * 12;

    if (!Renderer->Initialized)
    {
        glGenBuffers(1, &Renderer->VBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Renderer->VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Size * 2, 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenVertexArrays(1, &Renderer->VAO);
        glBindVertexArray(Renderer->VAO);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, 0);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        Renderer->Initialized = 1;
    }

    /*r32 *VertPos = Calloc(Size, r32);
    r32 *VertUV = Calloc(Size, r32);*/

    // Temporary code, just trying to render a single character on screen
    r32 VertPos[12]; // we need a quad <=> 2 triangles <=> 6 vertices <=> 12 floats
    r32 VertUV[12]; // same for UVs

    For(u32, i, NumChars) // for loop macro
    {
        font_character Character = Font->Characters[Renderer->Text[i]]; // assuming that 'Characters' are ordered correctly
        r32 X = Character.X;
        r32 Y = Character.Y;
        r32 XOffset = Character.XOffset;
        r32 YOffset = Character.YOffset;
        r32 XAdvance = Character.XAdvance;
        r32 Width = Character.Width;
        r32 Height = Character.Height;

        // Triangle 1 (clock-wise winding order)
        {
            // Top Left
            VertPos[i] = Renderer->CurrentX + XOffset;
            VertPos[i + 1] = YOffset;

            // Bottom Left
            VertPos[i + 2] = Renderer->CurrentX + XOffset;
            VertPos[i + 3] = YOffset + Height;

            // Bottom Right
            VertPos[i + 4] = Renderer->CurrentX + XOffset + Width;
            VertPos[i + 5] = YOffset + Height;
        }
        // Triangle 2
        {
            // Bottom Right
            VertPos[i + 6] = VertPos[i + 4];
            VertPos[i + 7] = VertPos[i + 5];

            // Top Right
            VertPos[i + 8] = Renderer->CurrentX + XOffset + Width;
            VertPos[i + 9] = YOffset;

            // Top Left
            VertPos[i + 10] = VertPos[i];
            VertPos[i + 11] = VertPos[i + 1];
        }

        // UV 1
        {
            // Top left
            VertUV[i] = X / Font->Width;
            VertUV[i + 1] = Y / Font->Height;

            // Bottom left
            VertUV[i + 2] = X / Font->Width;
            VertUV[i + 3] = (Y + Height) / Font->Height;

            // Bottom right
            VertUV[i + 4] = (X + Width) / Font->Width;
            VertUV[i + 5] = (Y + Height) / Font->Height;
        }

        // UV 2
        {
            // Bottom right
            VertUV[i + 6] = VertUV[i + 4];
            VertUV[i + 7] = VertUV[i + 5];

            // Top right
            VertUV[i + 8] = (X + Width) / Font->Width;
            VertUV[i + 9] = Y / Font->Height;

            // Top left
            VertUV[i + 10] = VertUV[i];
            VertUV[i + 11] = VertUV[i + 1];
        }
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Renderer->VBO);
    u32 Offset = 0;
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Offset, Size, VertPos);
    Offset += Size;
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Offset, Size, VertUV);

    m4 FontProjection = Orthographic(0, 800, 600, 0, -1, +1);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    ShaderUse(Renderer->Shader);
    glBindVertexArray(Renderer->VAO);
    TextureBind(Font->Atlas);
    ShaderSetV3(Renderer->Shader, "Color", Renderer->Color);
    ShaderSetM4(Renderer->Shader, "Projection", &FontProjection);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumChars * 6);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

As you can see I'm really just trying to get a single character on screen. I'm not even taking into consideration the font size etc just keeping it simple. I choose the vertices going from `TopLeft->BottomLeft->BottomRight->TopRight->TopLeft` which, correct me if I'm wrong but is a clock-wise winding order. I have two slots in my vertex shader: Position and UV. I'm specifying the buffer data via the call to `glBufferSubData`

Running the program I don't get any rendering output. Just blank screen. Pretty sure I'm missing something obvious or doing something stupid, I can't see it. What am I doing wrong?

Note that the texture, font data and shader are loaded all correctly.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to have a number of problems (even ignoring the horrible C-in-C++ coding style you employ). I haven't found all of them, so I can't say I found the one that you ran into.

But I did find these:

---

```
u32 Size = NumChars * 12;
```

You use `Size * 2` as the size for your buffer. So each character in your string takes up 24 bytes; 12 for your positions and 12 for your texture coordinates.

But your positions and texcoords are `float`s. 4 bytes per float * 2 floats per position * 6 positions per character = 48 bytes per character.

So your size calculation is very off. You can verify this by checking `sizeof(VertPos)` and comparing that to your `Size` variable. You'll find that they're very different.

---

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, 0);
```

This says that your position and texture coordinate both have the same offset. That would mean that your position and texcoord in the shader will get *the same value*. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want.

Your texture coordinate array comes from a different part of the buffer. So you need to apply an appropriate offset. Assuming you have correctly computed `Size`, that would look like this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, reinterpret_cast<void*>(Size));
```

Comment: Awesome! Working perfectly now! - Yeah I forgot that I should be dealing with bytes, I thought OpenGL would do the `* sizeof(float)` for me. About the coding style, I don't see how it's relevant to the question being asked, not sure what you're complaining about, code in whatever style fits you.