# Bitmap fonts not rendering correctly for some characters

Tags: c++, text, graphics, bitmap

I am generating the bitmap font texture from here - https://snowb.org/

The font for "**Name - wxyz**" is rendering as below -

[image: example]

The code is very much similar to the one posted for this question - [Bitmap font rendering issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013584/bitmap-font-rendering-issue), so I will only post my code for the quad and texture coordinate calculation for the characters (I am using orthographic projection with identity view matrix)-

```
// beginOffsetX and beginOffsetY is just some offset where I want the text to appear
// fontAtlasWidth and fontAtlasHeight is size of texture
// texData contains all the parameters that can be read from the font.txt generated from the same bitmap generator website (parameters are described later below)

   float xAdvance = 0.0f;
   fontVertices.resize(texData.size() * 4);
   fontTexCoords.resize(texData.size() * 4);
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < texData.size(); i++)
   {
      float xcoordBegin = beginOffsetX + xAdvance;
      float xcoordEnd = beginOffsetX + xAdvance + texData[i].width;
      float ycoordBegin = beginOffsetY;
      float ycoordEnd = beginOffsetY + texData[i].height;

      fontVertices[4u * i + 0] = geometry_utils::vec3{ xcoordBegin, ycoordEnd, 0.0f };
      fontVertices[4u * i + 1] = geometry_utils::vec3{ xcoordBegin, ycoordBegin, 0.0f };
      fontVertices[4u * i + 2] = geometry_utils::vec3{ xcoordEnd, ycoordEnd, 0.0f };
      fontVertices[4u * i + 3] = geometry_utils::vec3{ xcoordEnd, ycoordBegin, 0.0f };

      float xtexcoordBegin = texData[i].x;
      float xtexcoordEnd = texData[i].x + texData[i].width / fontAtlasWidth;
      float ytexcoordBegin = texData[i].y;
      float ytexcoordEnd = texData[i].y + texData[i].height / fontAtlasHeight;

      fontTexCoords[4u * i + 0] = geometry_utils::vec2{ xtexcoordBegin, ytexcoordBegin };
      fontTexCoords[4u * i + 1] = geometry_utils::vec2{ xtexcoordBegin, ytexcoordEnd };
      fontTexCoords[4u * i + 2] = geometry_utils::vec2{ xtexcoordEnd, ytexcoordBegin };
      fontTexCoords[4u * i + 3] = geometry_utils::vec2{ xtexcoordEnd, ytexcoordEnd };

      xAdvance += texData[i].width;
   }
```

**Issue** -

As you can see some of the fonts are not rendering correctly. Small case 'y' is appearing as capital 'Y', hyphen '-' is appearing as '_', and space ' ' is not appearing at all.
The font text file generated from https://snowb.org/ contains these parameters for every character from ascii 32 to 125, below is one example-

`char id=33 x=331 y=52 width=14 height=42 xoffset=-1 yoffset=-1 xadvance=13 page=0 chnl=15`

Out of these, as you can see in the above code, I am using only x,y, width, height and xAdvance. Attempting to use xOffset/fontAtlasWidth and yoffset/fontAtlasHeight in the texture coordinates did not fix these issues and also further messed up the other characters.

Could you please guide me as to what I need to modify in my calculations to get all the characters to render correctly?

**Edit**:

Adding the y-offset as this,

```
      float xtexcoordBegin = texData[i].x;
      float xtexcoordEnd = texData[i].x + texData[i].width / fontAtlasWidth ;
      float ytexcoordBegin = texData[i].y - texData[i].yOffset / fontAtlasHeight;
      float ytexcoordEnd = texData[i].y + texData[i].height / fontAtlasHeight;
```

results in image like this

[image]

This is if the yoffset is added instead -

[image]

Comment: Clearly the _y_ is not a capital Y. Instead it seems that `y` is shifted up (and `-` is shifted down) to "compress" the font data, i.e. to avoid allocating data for pixels below the baseline. I would expect `'x'` and `'z'` to have completely different yoffsets compared to `'y'`.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen  yes, sorry..i mentioned that it "appears" as capital 'Y', didn't mean to confuse. The offsets for x, y and z seem to be the same


`char id=120 x=163 y=230 width=31 height=33 xoffset=-4 yoffset=8 xadvance=23 page=0 chnl=15

char id=121 x=166 y=0 width=31 height=42 xoffset=-4 yoffset=8 xadvance=23 page=0 chnl=15

char id=122 x=229 y=68 width=30 height=33 xoffset=-4 yoffset=8 xadvance=23 page=0 chnl=15`
Also, as I already mentioned, using these offsets was actually messing up the other characters as well

Comment: Ok, the yoffsets indeed are the same, but that's because I guessed the offset to be on the bottom. The offset is from the top, and the capital XYZ have offsety = 6, while lower case xyz have offsety = 22. The characters are top aligned, not bottom aligned as I suspected.

Comment: How were you using these offsets? To me it seems, these are writing offsets, xoffset is often called kerning, and yoffset means the amount pixels that the whole quad needs to be shifted down. But this also means, that when these characters are rendered, the bounding boxes may overlap -- and then one needs to actually blend (or mask) the new character to the canvas instead of copying.

Comment: Have updated the question by showing the usage of yoffset..have shown result with both adding and subtracting...still doesnt look ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that worked for me with the code I have added to the question was to modify the y vertex coordinate as such

```
      float ycoordBegin = beginOffsetY - texData[i].height - texData[i].yOffset;
      float ycoordEnd = beginOffsetY - texData[i].yOffset;
```

With this modification the text appears correctly as below -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, the offsets have different meaning.

`x,y` and `width, height` are the input coordinates, where as `xoffset`, `yoffset` are writing coordinates.

The whole rendering process should go something like this (in pseudo code)

```
int cursor_x = 0;
int cursor_y = 0;

for (auto const &i : my_string) {
    auto const &tex = texData[i]; // let throw if not found
    for (int y = 0; y < tex.height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < tex.width; x++) {
            auto x_pos = x + cursor_x + tex.xoffset;
            auto y_pos = y + cursor_y + tex.yoffset;

            my_canvas.setPixel(x_pos, y_pos,
                font_png.getPixel(x + tex.x, y + tex.y));
        }
    }
    cursor_x += tex.xadvance;
}
```